# need sql query to sum the values based on a key and to find the maximum value out of it

Tags: sql, hive

need sql query to sum the values based on a key and to find the maximum value out of it ?

example:
rollno, name, class, marks. I need the max marks for each class ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Select 
    Name, Class, max(Max_Marks)
From 
(
   Select RollNo, Name, CLass, max(Marks) [Max_Marks]
   From YourTable
   Group By Class, Name, RollNo
)
Group By
    Name, Class
```

Comment: Thank you. what will be the query in the below case. Rollno, name, class, subject, marks. here we need to sum the marks for each student for all the subjects. and then to find the max mark scored by an student for each class....

Comment: @Janu Well you can achieve that yourself by referring this!

Comment: select a.rollno, a.name, a.class, a.school, max(a.total) from (select rollno, name, class, school, sum(marks) as total from students group by rollno, name, class, school) a group by a.rollno, a.name, a.class, a.school;   i tried this query.... but still it is getting the summed values for each class and each student and not getting the max value scored by an student for each class

Comment: select max(a.total) from (select rollno, name, class, school, sum(marks) as total from students group by rollno, name, class, school) a;... this is getting me the max score but not the student details that too only the maxscore and not for each class....

Comment: select max(a.total) from (select rollno, name, class, school, sum(marks) as total from students group by rollno, name, class, school order by total) a group by a.class;... with this query, i am getting max score for each class... how to get the student details also in the output.....

Comment: Select 
    Name, Class, max(Max_Marks)
From 
(
   Select RollNo, Name, CLass, max(Marks) [Max_Marks]
   From YourTable
   Group By Class, Name, RollNo
)
Group By
    Name, Class